# schedule moving of messages from activemq DLQ to another queue in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

Wanted to know if there is any configuration that can be done in a activeMQ server that will re direct the messages from the DLQ to another queue on the same server.

For Example.

I have a queue "MAINQUEUE" which has a lot of messages having client ack activated, while processing if I get any exception the messages are transferred to the DLQ after some retries as expected.  But I want the messages which are in the DLQ to be moved back into the MAINQUEUE after some time i.e. 5-10 min . 
Is there any way I can configure for it to be done automatically or I have to do it manually by writing a code.

Thanks
FX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default mechanism for this, moving messages out of DLQ is generally considered a devops task as it should be determined why they are ending up there in the first place.

If you want to do something like that you could consider using an [embedded](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component.html) Camel route, or use the broker [interceptor](http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html) pattern to create such a redirect to the scheduler.

Comment: Interessting, so such poisoned messages are intended to be processed by hands?